# addToSet if not already present

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I have a schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MySchema = new Schema({
    Theme: { type: String },
    Style: { type: String },
    Brand: { type: String },
    UpdatedInfo: [
            {
             _id:false, 
             ThisDate: { type: String },
             NewInfo: {type: String },
             OriginalInfo: {type: String }
            }
    ]    
}, { versionKey: false });
```

I then do an update:

```
MySchema.update({ Theme: MyTheme }, {
   $addToSet: {
      UpdatedInfo: {
         ThisDate: TheDate,
         NewInfo: TheNewInfo,
         OriginalInfo: TheOriginalInfo
      },
   }
},function (err, result) {
   next(err,result);
});
```

That query adds a new element to the `UpdatedInfo` array every new `TheDate`, even if `TheNewInfo` and `TheOriginalInfo` is the same in that new element of `UpdatedInfo`.
What I want is to add a new element to `UpdatedInfo` **only** if `NewInfo` did change from the `NewInfo` in `UpdatedInfo` array element with the latest `ThisDate` date.

Right now the `UpdatedInfo` array looks like following:

```
"UpdatedInfo" : [ 
    {
        "ThisDate" : "12/15/2015",
        "NewInfo" : "12 500:-",
        "OriginalInfo" : "15 000:-"
    }, 
    {
        "ThisDate" : "12/16/2015",
        "NewInfo" : "12 500:-",
        "OriginalInfo" : "15 000:-"
    }, 
    {
        "ThisDate" : "12/17/2015",
        "NewInfo" : "12 500:-",
        "OriginalInfo" : "15 000:-"
    }
]
```

And if `UpdatedInfo` is empty from the beginning, it should add the first element to it, i.e. :

```
"UpdatedInfo" : [ 
    {
        "ThisDate" : "12/17/2015",
        "NewInfo" : "12 500:-",
        "OriginalInfo" : "15 000:-"
    }
]
```

Is it possible?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch` to check if an element that matches TheOriginalInfo, has it's NewInfo outdated while ignoring ThisDate alltogether:

```
MySchema.update(
  {
    UpdatedInfo: {
      $elemMatch: {
        OriginalInfo: TheOriginalInfo,
        NewInfo: {$ne: TheNewInfo}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "UpdatedInfo.$.NewInfo": TheNewInfo,
      "UpdatedInfo.$.ThisDate": TheDate
    }
  }
);
```

Read about [$ (update)](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/).

If you need advanced interactions with an array or a set, I'd suggest you move it out to a collection.

MongoDB does much more with collections than with arrays.

Comment: I did have UpdatedPrice as the collection before. But it duplicated array elements in that collection then...

Comment: @user1665355 I added some solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, when you say try $elemMatch, do you mean that you are not sure that it will work?:)

Comment: @user1665355 $elemMatch works very well. But I don't know if my solution fits your schema :P

Comment: Ok I will try. But do you think it will work if my `UpdatedInfo` array already contains a few elements with the same `NewInfo` elements?

Comment: @user1665355 For this to work, OriginalInfo must be unique to every element, regardless of how ThisDate or NewInfo change. If OriginalInfo isn't unique, try introducing some new field that is. The `NewInfo: {$ne: TheNewInfo}` checks if the element is outdated and the `$set` updates all matching (outdated) elements with the $ update.

Comment: Please see my update about how `UpdatedInfo` looks right now. Would be grateful if you could update your answer to match it :)

Comment: @user1665355 This should work as it is. Is there any issue?

Comment: ok I will try. Thought that it would not because UpdatePrice have several elements with same OriginalInfo and NewInfo. Sorry for maybe stupid question, quiet new to mongo still :) So `elementMatch` matches all the elements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98214/discussion-between-zippoxer-and-user1665355).